# Помогите решить ошибку с interface android

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер, retrofit2

У меня есть приложение в котором я пытаюсь реализовать функцию логина при помощи логина и пароля, и вот у меня возникла ошибка

```
error: method savePost in interface APIService cannot be applied to given types;
required: Post
found: String,String
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

метод savepost в интерфейсе:

```
@POST("v1/login/{login}{password}")
Call<Post> savePost(@Body Post body);
```

а потом этот-же метод вызывается в mainactivity:

```
mAPIService.savePost(login, password).enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Post> call, @NonNull Response<Post> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    showResponse(response.body().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"post submitted to API.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Unable to submit post to API.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

я никак не могу понять в чем проблема, если смотреть по ошибке именно то получается что у меня необходимо post а нашло два string. У меня на сервере ждут просто json который я должен вытащить с двух полей для ввода. И я не могу понять в чем проблема, у меня вообще не посылается запрос на сервер.Также у меня есть класс для отправки сериализации данных перед отправкой на сервер:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Post {
    @SerializedName("login")
    private String login;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public Post(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin (String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "User login ='" + login + '\'' +
                ", password ='" + password + '}';
    }
}
```

Если кто-то знает в чем проблема буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш метод: `Call<Post> savePost(@Body Post body)`, — это значит, что он принимает один входной параметр. А вы передаёте два: `savePost(login, password)`.

Вам стоит поступить так:

Создайте класс, который будет выступать телом для запроса после его сериализации:

```
class LoginBody {
    private String login, password;

    // геттеры, сеттеры, конструкторы не забудьте
}
```

И затем вызываете:

```
mAPIService.savePost(new LoginBody(login, password))
```

Ваш объект будет сериализован в следующий json:

```
{ "login": "значение переменной login", "password": "значение переменной password" }
```

Но для автоматической де/сериализации не забудьте в билдере при инициализации вашего объекта `retrofit` указать `GsonConverterFactory`.

И также, конечно же, сигнатуру метода тоже придётся подправить:

```
@POST("v1/login/{login}{password}")
Call<Post> savePost(@Body LoginBody body);
```

И зачем вы используете `/{login}{password}`? Это будет заменено в итоге на `/user1234password1234` при логине `user1234` и пароле `password1234`, каким образом бэкенд определит, где закончился логин и начался пароль?

И тем более, для того, чтобы внутри `@POST("вот здесь")` что-то заменялось, необходимо передать дополнительные входные параметры с аннотацией `@Path`.

---

<sub>Более развёрнутый пример (в комментариях неудобно, да и не стоит отвечать).</sub>

**Вот такой вот метод:**

```
@POST("/v1/login/{parameter_0}/{parameter_1}")
Call<SomeResponse> auth(@Body LoginBody body, @Path("parameter_0") p0, @Path("parameter_1") p1);
```

**Нужно вызывать так:**

```
String a = "qwerty";
String b = "abcdef";
api.auth(new LoginBody(login, password), a, b);
```

**В итоге будет отправлен запрос по такому адресу:**

```
https://адрес_сервера/v1/login/qwerty/abcdef
```

**С таким телом:**

```
{ "login": "значение login", "password": "значение password" }
```

Адрес сервера, очевидно, передаете при инициализации билдера `retrofit`.

Comment: обновил вопрос, вы такой класс имеете в виду?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, и аннотации `@SerializedName` не нужны, если имя поля объекта совпадает с именем поля в конечной json-структуре.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko вы сделали всё правильно, кроме непосредственно вызова метода. Передавайте туда не два параметра, а один — новый объект.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko дополнил ответ. Обратите внимание на другие ошибки.

Comment: а как можно в Call<Post> savePost(@Body Post body); вставить @Path ведь там есть уже Body? и я сколько раз спрашиваю, и все никак не могу понять какой должен быть адрес в скобках POST?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko а кто вам мешает? Какие хотите, такие параметры и указывайте на вход метода. Главное чтобы вы их сами потом передали, только вы его и вызываете

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko дополнил ответ.

Comment: а у вас в указанном вами методе, в call<some responce> наличие some responce обязательно?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko зачем вы так буквально всё воспринимаете? Это всего лишь пример. Подставляйте свои данные, изучите больше базы, чтобы такие сложные примеры писать

Comment: ок спасибо большое за помощь, вы мне помогли решить мой вопрос